Is it possible to start UWP application without showing it?
I'm making a WPF application to project desktop screen to a wireless display. But this function is only availabe in UWP, check this Microsoft official sample: https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/main/Samples/Projection/cs
So another way is to call projection function of UWP application from WPF application, two processes coexit. Then the issue is how to hide or minimize UWP window. Due to the projection function ProjectionManager.StartProjectingAsync() takes something like ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Id as arguments, which is under namespace Windows.UI.ViewManagement of UWP GUI only (WinRT).
Any idea?

We can't launch uwp app without showing window or splash screen. you can Minimize UWP programmatically.

Are you aware that a UWP app will be suspended when it is minimized? There are a few exceptions but I am not sure they might help in your case. Postpone app suspension with extended execution

Run something else in the foreground at full screen while the uwp app initializes? Even if it's "black"; or partially opaque. (Have used a "sliding" translucent panel during "sign on" in one app)

Currently, UWP GUI cannot be started without showing window or splash screen. You can minimize it after opening it.
Of course, after minimizing, you need to execute your API in a backgroundTask,  you may need to run it indefinitely.
IList<AppDiagnosticInfo> infos = await AppDiagnosticInfo.RequestInfoForAppAsync();

IList<AppResourceGroupInfo> resourceInfos = infos[0].GetResourceGroups();

await resourceInfos[0].StartSuspendAsync();

